# JSON response get method of url with authentication

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to get the JSON response from a URL having authentication, The code is mentioned below

```
$.getJSON({
    'url': 'http://test.etravelsmart.com/etsAPI/api/getStations',
    'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
        //May need to use "Authorization" instead
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication","Basic " + encodeBase64("*****" + ":" + "****"))
    },
    success: function(result) {
         alert(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
               var StationId = field.stationId;
               var StationName = field.stationName;
                $("#txtLabourId").append("<option>" + StationName + "</option>");
           });
    }
 });
```

I am trying to display the values in a

```
<select id="txtLabourId"></select>
```

But having authentication i am not getting the response. All help appreciated

Comment: have you checked response code?

Comment: Yes, its valid.

Comment: what is the result of `alert(result)` ?

Comment: What you getting in alert(result) ?

Comment: In fact its not going inside `function(result)` , So i cannot alert()

Comment: so I think the response status is 4xx or 5xx, try to debug the response in your browser or use `$.ajax` with an **error** handler to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

The remote resource `http://test.etravelsmart.com/etsAPI/api/getStations` is not available to you via JavaScript. See [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource) and answers for information.

---

You also have some errors regarding your use of the jQuery methods.

You are passing an AJAX config object where [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) expects a `url` string.

Instead, use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) where you can also take advantage of the `username` and `password` properties...

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://test.etravelsmart.com/etsAPI/api/getStations',
  dataType: 'json',
  username: '*****',
  password: '****'
}).done(function(result) {
  // etc
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.error(textStatus, errorThrown)
})
```

Comment: No sir, Still i am not able to retrieve the data

Comment: @ShreyasBandimat and the glaring error message in your console is...?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.etravelsmart.com/etsAPI/api/getStations. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: Its the error i am getting in console

Comment: do you have access to the server code ? the easiest way to solve this problem is to add this header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on server side

Comment: @oliv37 I suggest you post your comment on the question above so Shreyas can see it. This is just an answer